# Arduino does not run

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

The code below is compiled but does not generate any output at the terminal. The data memory used is 9% and code 5%. The Arduino only generates outputs when the MAX variable is set to values less than 1769.

The Algorithm below is used to generate prime numbers from an upper limit. I know that the Arduino platform does not have this purpose, but this project is part of a study of memories.

```cpp
#define MAX 2000

void setup() {
  int i,j;
  int limite;
  char ehprimo[MAX];   
   
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for(i=2;i<MAX;i++) ehprimo[i]=1;
  limite = (int)sqrt(MAX);
  
  for(i=2;i<=limite;i++) {
    if(ehprimo[i]) {
      for(j=i*i;j<MAX;j=j+i)
        ehprimo[j] = 0;
    }
  }

  for(i=2;i<MAX;i++) {
    if(ehprimo[i]) {
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(i);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
 
}
```

Comment: For starters, you should probably move the main processing to the `loop()` function. The `setup()` function is surely the wrong place for it.

Comment: @zx485 can I execute a function only once in the loop, or will it be running and spending processing all the time?

Comment: Usually, the `loop()` function runs as long as the Arduino is powered-on. But of course you can use a `boolean` to indicate to skip the main code after the first successful result.

Comment: IIRC you can call a "power-save" function after you completed your task to put the Arduino into a lew-resource-using mode. This would reduce the power consumption from mW to µW.

Comment: @zx485 if you want to run your code once setup is perfectly fine.

Comment: This is the very essence of "no research effort."  Your "study of memories" should have started with understanding the memory constraints of your device, and of reading the compiler's output and messages.

Answer (score 1):

You're running out of memory.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/memory

Your char array alone would consume 2000 bytes of the available 2048 bytes SRAM.

Of course you need memory for other variables as well which causes your program to fail with even smaller MAX values.